# Possible forward declaration error

Tags: c++

I have two files. One is main.cpp which #includes "MouseController.h" which has my classdef for a Mouse object. If MouseController.h has no imports or includes at all, why does main have problems finding my Mouse class?

If its any use, the CMD-Click of Xcode that lets you trace a something back to its declaration finds the Mouse class ok.

Main.cpp

```
#include <GLUT/GLUT.h>
#include <OpenGL/OpenGL.h>
#include <iostream>

#import "MouseController.h"

Mouse mouse;

float angle = 0.0f;

void selfInit();
void glInit();
void DisplayCallback();
void ReshapeCallback(int w, int h);
void UpdateAll(int value);


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    selfInit();
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glInit();

    return 0;
}
```

Theres no more reference to the mouse object after here.

MouseController.h

```
#ifndef __FinalPiece__MouseController__
#define __FinalPiece__MouseController__

class Mouse {
    public:
    static int CurrentX;
    static int CurrentY;
    static int LastX;
    static int LastY;
    static int DeltaX;
    static int DeltaY;

    static void move(int x, int y);
    static void update();
    static void clicked(int button, int state, int x, int y);
};
#endif
```

Comment: Could you post some code, or at least the specific error you're experiencing?

Comment: some piece of code and the compiler error you got will be welcome!

Comment: Theres no error messages, it wont build, the only thing i have to go on is unknown type name "Mouse"

Comment: Please post the code, we don't know what a "Mouse" type is.

Comment: `#import "MouseController.h"` I guess you want to write `#include "MouseController.h"`

Comment: When Xcode added the files, it shoved them in the wrong directory, so the xcode file browser could find them but nothing else could. My apologies for wasting your time.

Comment: @TomásBadan `#import` is completely fine, it's a Microsoft thing used for COM and .NET stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing your code, it is a shot in the dark, but it sounds like you are getting a linker error.

```
// main.cpp
#include "MouseController.h"

int main()
{
    // do stuff
    return 0;
}

// MouseController.cpp
#include "MouseController.h"

// implement MouseController here

// MouseController.h
// define MouseController here
```

If MouseController.cpp does not exist, is not being compiled (i.e. is not part of your project or Makefile), or MouseController.h does not implement the class inline, the compiler knows what MouseController should look like, but the linker can't find it.

Comment: The "does not exist" you mentioned was spot on. Or rather, because the file was 1 directory to high but still in the right folder, it wasnt finding and so wasnt linking it. Thanks